Hide VAT in WooCommerce for specific user only on frontend
I use the following to hide VAT from non-professional users on the front end. My problem is that when an order is placed, the VAT remains zero, leading to incorrect calculations. Products are created with prices excluding VAT. For non-professional users, the product price should be the price excluding VAT plus VAT, resulting in the final price including VAT.
However, I can't use 'excl' and 'incl' because I have a special display of prices at different stages: cart, checkout, and order. Is there a way to hide VAT only on the front end for specific users?
function zero_rate_for_custom_user_role( $tax_class, $product ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $is_pro_user = 'yes' == get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'professionnel', true );
        if ( !$is_pro_user ) {
            $tax_class = 'zero-rate';
        }
    }else{
        $tax_class = 'zero-rate';
    }
    
    return $tax_class;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_tax_class','zero_rate_for_custom_user_role', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'zero_rate_for_custom_user_role', 10, 2 );


The products are priced with HT. On the website frontend, when the user is not a professional, the price of the product will be displayed as follows: the original price in HT + VAT to make it the TTC (including tax) price, and VAT is not calculated in the cart or order. So, when I use the zero-rate tax class for non-professional users, the calculation on the website is correct. However, when checking orders in the admin dashboard, we see that VAT is disabled and the product price is displayed as HT. There is an inconsistency between the order price on the frontend and in the backend.

The problem still , In back office the the VAT is disabled .It should be activated .

You can't really hide VAT from customer displayed prices and totals and have it enabled in the backend. It is absolutely not logical.

The only way should be to change the displayed prices and calculated totals everywhere overriding all related templates, but it's going to be a nightmare (long and complicated). And if you are using blocks, specifically cart and checkout blocks, I don't know if it's even possible.

Why not just add % discount same as VAT ?
